# MongoDB::listCollections not working

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

Within Symfony Doctrine i'm using MongoDB as database. I need to have a list of all the collections within a database.

I thought the method `ListCollections()` would give me these as the name and documentation suggests.
Except this function doesn't return me anything at all.

From Symfony PHP i'm calling the method like this:

`$this->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_connection')->selectDatabase('database');`

This gives me an instance of the class `Doctrine\MongoDB\Database`
This class has the function `listCollection()` as stated below:

```
/**
 * Wrapper method for MongoDB::listCollections().
 *
 * @see http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.listcollections.php
 * @return array
 */
public function listCollections()
{
    return $this->mongoDB->listCollections();
}
```

As the documentation would suggest this function should return an array which it does (yet it's empty even tho there are collections within my database).

So I moved deeper and looked at the documentation of `listCollections()` of the mongo pecl plugin which states:

```
/**
 * (PECL mongo >= 0.9.0)<br/>
 * Get a list of collections in this database
 * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.listcollections.php
 * @param bool $includeSystemCollections [optional] <p>Include system collections.</p>
 * @return array Returns a list of MongoCollections.
 */
 public function listCollections($includeSystemCollections = false) {}
```

How would one get all the collection names within one database within Symfony 3.0.6?

Some critical details:

- Mongo version: 1.5.5
- Symfony version: 3.0.6
- MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongo 1.5.5 has a bug which creates this.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver-legacy/blob/1.5.5/db.c

Try updating the mongo extension to 1.6.14 and try again!